# Boot android and run process at the same time

Tags: android, c, process, android-source, boot

I created 1 program test and I want to run program test immediately after boot android

This is my file.rc

```
service test /system/bin/test
        class late_start
```

But the program test /system/bin/test don't run.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: have u start the service? :)

Comment: thanks, can you help me ? I have the question below.